# class not found exception :MyMapper.class not found

Tags: class, hadoop, mapreduce

i ran a hadoop map reduce program its mapping and reducing. but the error- **class not** **found exception i**s coming and in web interface of task tracker slave is not performing its job.I have enough of memory space and have run other programs which worked fine . i have all the .class files also and output is also correct. **how to remove class not found exception so that slave too can work on the jobs.**

Comment: Can you post the exact exception you are seeing. Can you also confirm how you are submitting the job (the command line your are eecuting), and that your Mapper class files are bundled into a jar

Answer (score 0):

The possible cause for the problem might be missing "SetJarByClass" call in your driver. In this case job will start, but task trackers will not have Your classes.

Comment: we have included setjarbyclass for main class,should it include the mapper and reducer class also???

Comment: No, one class is enough, if they sit in the same jar.

Comment: thank you.. realised that v wer creating same jar for different programs.. may be that was the problem.now everything works fine.